# letsencrypt ssl on emqtt

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, lets-encrypt, emq

I am using Emqtt 2.3.3version. I'm trying to implement ssl using lets encrypt. I am using below steps to implement the same

sudo apt-get update,sudo apt-get install software-properties-common,sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot,sudo apt-get update,sudo apt-get install certbot

sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d example.com
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/chain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/zhengyupan.de/cert.pem

/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/cert.pem: OK

I changed below configuration in emq
listener.ssl.external.keyfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/privkey.pem
listener.ssl.external.certfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domaion/fullchain.pem

cat /etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/chain.pem > ca.pem

mosquitto_sub -t abc -h $domain -p 8883 -d  --cafile ~/ca.pem

if i subsribe i am getting error like connection timed out